# Downloadable list of Romance-language cognates?

Tags: nlp, online-resources, cognates

I'm looking for tables of cognates between French, Spanish and Italian (and potentially Latin, Portuguese, Catalan, etc.), so I can run some Python on them.

If they could have extra information such as frequency, pronunciation, meaning, etc. that would be nice too. (I don't need them right away but may in the future).

(So far the best ways I see would be either through wiktionary, or by running some kind of distance metrics on translations to find likely cognates. But I'm pretty certain *somebody* already did something like that)